# How to make a global ~/.vimrc?

Tags: linux, centos, unix, vim

Right now, I make everyone do ~/.vimrc and put their settings there.

How can I make a global, default *.vimrc* for new users?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

usually by creating /etc/vimrc or /etc/vim/vimrc.  Depends on your version of vim and linux/unix

Comment: I am using CentOS

Comment: should be /etc/vimrc on CentOs

Comment: It is /etc/vimrc

Comment: Doesn't work on Solaris

Comment: I'd personally suggest `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`, at least on Ubuntu 16. It gets sourced by `/etc/vim/vimrc` and means you don't have to hack at the default file.

Answer (score 15):

to create a default ~/.vimrc for all new users, you should be able to drop it into /etc/skel

If I recall correctly, that provides the template for new user's home directories.

Answer (score 12):

In Debian, it appears the file you are looking for is:

```
/etc/vim/vimrc
```

It might be different in a different distro (though I think that is not much likely).

Good luck.

Comment: By default it sources `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` which would be safer for updates

Answer (score 9):

See `:help system-vimrc`:

> For Unix, MS-DOS, MS-Windows, OS/2, VMS, Macintosh, RISC-OS and Amiga
>           the system vimrc file is read for initializations.  *The path of this
>           file is shown with the ":version" command.  Mostly it's "$VIM/vimrc".*
>           Note that this file is ALWAYS read in 'compatible' mode, since the
>           automatic resetting of 'compatible' is only done later.  Add a ":set
>           nocp" command if you like.

So, put your system configurations in this file. Type `:help version` in vim to see where, or `echo $VIM` at the shell to see if `$VIM` is defined. (Note that you may have to set `$VIM` for all users, such as in a system bashrc file.)

Answer (score 0):

for MacVim, it's at 
`/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-98/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

Vim appears to have changed to loading a `defaults.vim` file **last** in the absence of `~/.vimrc`.  Until this is addressed, I figured I need to load `defaults.vim` in `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` the way a sample `vimrc_example.vim` shows, set a flag to prevent the automatic loading of `defaults.vim` last and **then** set own preferences in the same file.

```
 " Get the defaults that most users want.
 source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
+let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1
```

https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2917#issuecomment-631908139